# Prolog Bad Syntax, expecting operator.

Tags: syntax, prolog

I keep getting this operator:

```
Syntax error: Operator expected
```

On line 3 of my code.

```
rotationsAndPlayers(Rotations,Maze):-
    length(Rotations) + length(findPlayers(generateList(Maze))) % 2 is 0.

generateList([]).
generateList([H|T]):-
    append(H | generateList(T)).

findPlayers([], Result):- Result.
findPlayers([H|T], Result):-
    ((numlist(1,4,NL), member(H, NL)) -> findPlayers(T, Result + 1), findPlayers(T, Result)).
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have a significant misunderstanding of Prolog. It has *predicates*, not *functions*. `generateList` does not *return*  a list, and `length` is not a function you perform on the list that then returns a value. Prolog *predicates* define *relations* between their arguments. So `length(List, N)` says that the length of list `List` is `N` and will succeed if it's true, but fail if it's not true. It's unclear what your `generateList` is supposed to do. `append` requires 3 arguments. `append(A, B, C)` means `C` is the result of appending `B` to the end of `A`. Read some tutorials.

Comment: I know that I'm very bad at prolog, I'm currently trying to get better at it. Rotations contains a list of characters that represent rotations and Maze contains a list of lists that is the current board. There are between 1 and 4 players on the board (numbered likewise) and I'm trying to find if the number of rotations and the number of players summed is even or odd. The generate list method is just to take the list of lists and generate a list of the lists appended. If there is an easier way of doing all this, that would be great.

Comment: You should Google "prolog tutorial" and get basic understanding of how the language works. Also, run the interpreter (just run `swipl`) and try different things at the prompt to gain an understanding of its behavior.

Comment: I recommend you this online course: http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/